# Display multiple "blocks" of data from json file using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have a JSON file with objects that have their own titles and other characteristics. I'd like to use this data and append them as boxed elements in a page.

I haven't figured out how to use a dynamic number of blocks of data (depending on the JSON file).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using `length` ?

Comment: What have you already tried? I would suggest using a `for...of` loop to go through each value in the object to wrap them in a box

Comment: can you explain exactly what you have as input and what you want as html output (in a minimal version) ?

Comment: I have JSON file with courses. Each course has a title and a description. This list may change from time to time. How would I be able to get this data and display them in a site, with nice styling?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

today is a great day to learn about loops. since you didn't give us any code , i'll make an example that will answer (in general) how to do this.

```
<div id="demo">

</div>

<style>
    p {
        border: 2px solid black;
        width: 20%;
    }
</style>


<script>
 let object = {
     person1: {
         name: "bob",
         age: 30
     },
     person2: {
         name: "sherry",
         age: 35
     }
 }

let array = Object.keys(object);

Object.keys(object).forEach(function(key) {
    let name = object[key].name;
    let age = object[key].age;

    let p = document.createElement("P");
    let text = document.createTextNode(`name: ${name}, age: ${age}`);

    p.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(p);
});
</script>
```

since you didn't give an object (JSON) i made one up, but you can use this rough outline to style your own script around your data. However many name objects are in this object, thats how many times the code will run. so you could have 2, or 100, and each one will become its own box when the loop appends the element and the text to the document.

hope this helps

Comment: no problem, don't forget to mark the answer as the correct answer if it solved your question. cheers